# instantiate class from class object

Tags: java, class, new-operator

In java, can I use a class object to dynamically instantiate classes of that type?

i.e. I want some function like this.

```
Object foo(Class type) {
    // return new object of type 'type'
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In Java 9 and afterward, if there's a declared zero-parameter ("nullary") constructor, you'd use [`Class.getDeclaredConstructor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructor(java.lang.Class...)) to get it, then call [`newInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance(java.lang.Object...)) on it:

```
Object foo(Class type) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
    return type.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
}
```

Prior to Java 9, you would have used [`Class.newInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance()):

```
Object foo(Class type) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    return type.newInstance();
}
```

...but it was deprecated as of Java 9 because it threw any exception thrown by the constructor, even checked exceptions, but didn't (of course) declare those checked exceptions, effectively bypassing compile-time checked exception handling. `Constructor.newInstance` wraps exceptions from the constructor in `InvocationTargetException` instead.

Both of the above assume there's a zero-parameter constructor. A more robust route is to go through [`Class.getDeclaredConstructors`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructors()) or [`Class.getConstructors`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructors()), which takes you into using the Reflection stuff in the [`java.lang.reflect`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html) package, to find a constructor with the parameter types matching the arguments you intend to give it.

Comment: It looks like this approach has been deprecated since Java 9.

Comment: @dopatraman - It does, thanks, as of a couple of years ago. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
type.newInstance()
```

For creating an instance using the empty costructor, or use the method type.getConstructor(..) to get the relevant constructor and then invoke it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is called Reflection.  you can use the Class [`newInstance()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) method for this.

Comment: You can read more about it at: 
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/index.html

Also this post has very good information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful

Answer (score -1):

use newInstance() method.