# Functional Interface call for a new Instance

Tags: java, functional-programming

I need to write a functional interface call for a new instance of a dynamic object.

Classic way if I would know the class:

```
() -> new DefinedClass()
```

But I don't know the exact class. I only have the Class Object of the Class I try to instantiate.

Thx for help!

Comment: You can use the built-in `Supplier<DefinedClass>`

Comment: Do you mean? `Class clazz = ...; Object obj = clazz.newInstance()`?

Comment: newInstance() doesn't work in this functional context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [instantiate class from class object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036777/instantiate-class-from-class-object)

Comment: And why wouldn't newInstance() work? You're kinda supposed to explain yourself without being asked

Comment: Because the IDE tells me, "The target type of this expression must be a functional interface" when I use newInstance()

Comment: Can you show the code that gives you the error?

Comment: Its a Spring Boot Application

```
this.context.registerBean(beanInterface, bean.newInstance());
```

context is GenericWebApplicationContext

Comment: `registerBean` has lots of overloads, including one where you just need to pass constructor parameters (but not call the constructor yourself).

Answer (score 2):

```
package test;

import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream.of(Test.class)
                .map(c -> {
                    try {
                        return c.newInstance();
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException | InstantiationException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                })
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Test";
    }
}
```